# Select only date from column with datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
                  A
2002-01-03 12:00:00
2002-01-04 12:00:00
2002-01-05 12:00:00
```

I need to extract just the date from `df['A']`, which has datetime64[ns] format.

`df['A']` output should be:

```
         A
2002-01-03
2002-01-04
2002-01-05
```

I've tried:

```
datetime.strftime(df.A, '%y%m%d')
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want a `datetime` or `str` output. Either is possible:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2002-01-03 12:00:00',
                         '2002-01-04 12:00:00',
                         '2002-01-05 12:00:00']})

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

df['B'] = df['A'].dt.normalize()

df['C'] = df['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)

                    A          B           C
0 2002-01-03 12:00:00 2002-01-03  2002-01-03
1 2002-01-04 12:00:00 2002-01-04  2002-01-04
2 2002-01-05 12:00:00 2002-01-05  2002-01-05

print(df.dtypes)

A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
C            object
dtype: object
```